# find the query per username

Tags: sql, oracle, monitoring, performance-testing

i want to find all query run in period of time with the name of user run this query (username not session id )
 what should i do ?

Comment: What do you mean by "find all query"? What do you need - the full text of each query? Or just the query_id?

Comment: full text of query

Comment: i run a application and i want to find all query that this app run and after that find how much cpu these query use

Answer (score 0):

From the below one you can get the whole list of queries by schema wise.Check it.

```
SELECT V.SQL_TEXT,
           V.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME,
           V.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,
           V.DISK_READS,
           V.ROWS_PROCESSED,
           V.ELAPSED_TIME,
           V.SERVICE
      FROM V$SQL V
WHERE TO_DATE(V.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')>(TRUNC(SYSDATE)) 
AND PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME ='schema_name'
```

Comment: it has error : quoted string not properly terminated

Comment: what is the  database you using ?

Comment: SELECT V.SQL_TEXT,
           V.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME,
           V.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,
           V.DISK_READS,
           V.ROWS_PROCESSED,
           V.ELAPSED_TIME,
           V.SERVICE
      FROM V$SQL V
WHERE TO_DATE(V.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')>(TRUNC(SYSDATE))

Comment: just run the above query ..it will list out all you needed

Comment: Will it show the user's name? Where? Also, where did the OP ask about disk_reads, rows_processed, etc? What is this, graffiti?

Comment: thank you . it show a list of query , but dose not show this query itself , why?

Comment: Correct. Please answer my questions - how are you helping the guy? How is this helpful?

Comment: @mathguy  Even OP is satisfied with my answer ..then why you people doing like this..These things are too much sad about SO

Comment: @mathguy you guy having too much of reputations..so you wont bother about others..or low reputators

Comment: @mathguy please tell . why your query dose not show itself ?

Comment: @mathguy if iam doing any silly things in SO means, your action is correct..This is really horrible..cant digest..

Comment: @mathguy Never repeat this for anyone..Who learning through SO.. This will make them more depress on answering..If my answer is too far and not even relate to the question , then you can downvote me..it is happily accepted ..But this is done for  your shake of fun on lower reputators..

Comment: No. I do what I can to keep the quality of SO. Responding with a query that shows "elapsed time" when the OP asked for "username"? WHY? Either at least try to answer the OP's question, or refrain from posting.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this (not tested). The WHERE clause has two bind variables, one for your app's username and the other for the period over which you want to check all this.

```
select s.last_active_time, u.username, s.sql_id, c.cpu_time_total, s.sql_text
from   v$sql s join all_users u        on s.parsing_user_id = u.user_id
               join dba_hist_sqlstat c on s.sql_id          = c.sql_id
where  username          = :app_username
  and  last_active_time >= :from_date;
```

Comment: thank you. the cpu time that it show , is the cpu time that this query used in last run ? or sum of all cpu time that it use in all runs? and if i want cpu time use in a period of time , can i clear the table for special user and then run my app and see the exact cpu time that app use?

Comment: I am not sure (I don't do monitoring/tuning, I just offered something I thought may help you); if I was in your position, I would read the documentation for dba_hist_sqlstat, it should have answers to your questions.